# Why does my animation have a sliver of color at the top?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I can't figure out why there is a small line of color above my icon in my CSS animation. It seems like it's making two different objects when it animates the icon and they are overlapping but off slightly. Not sure why it's doing that. I'm also using icomoon to generate the icons. I've attached a GIF to show the issue.

[image: Sliver of color above the icon]

HTML

```
<div class="resources">
  <a href="/us/partners/resources/">
    <div class="icon-area">
     <i class="icon-channel-marketing-materials tera"></i>
     <span class="icon-channel-press"></span>
     <span class="icon-channel-screenshots"></span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="desc">
      <h3>Gather Tools</h3>
      <p>Browse go-to-market templates and customizable marketing materials.</p>
    </div>
    <span class="step-number">2</span>
   </a>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
/* Resources Step Animation */
.resources .icon-channel-press,
.resources .icon-channel-screenshots {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 800ms 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 800ms 0.4s;
    transition: all 800ms 0.4s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    color: #6D787F;
}
.resources .icon-channel-press {
    top: 100px;
    left: -30px;
    color: #5d8723;
}
.resources:hover .icon-channel-press {
    left:30px;
    top: 50px;
    font-size: 2.4em;
}
.resources .icon-channel-screenshots {
    top: 100px;
    right: -30px;
    color: #5d8723;
}
.resources:hover .icon-channel-screenshots {
    right:30px;
    top: 50px;
    font-size: 2.4em;
}
.resources:hover .icon-channel-marketing-materials {
    color: #8DC63F;
    -webkit-transition: color 800ms 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: color 800ms 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: color 800ms 0.4s;
    -o-transition: color 800ms 0.4s;
    transition: color 800ms 0.4s;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a (more or less) working example? Debugging would be much easier then!

Comment: Have you tried to border-top: none; also check your heights and widths to assure nothing is out of order allowing a few pixels to come through. Also try a simple * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate it by one pixel in the z direction to make the browser render it better

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
```